# How can I change the behavior of the $ operator in environments?

Tags: r

I want to override the behavior of the dollar operator, so that if I have

```
x <- new.env()
x$foo <- 3
```

will e.g. call something. I tried to look for possible functions such as `$`, but my knowledge of the internals is not good enough.

I tried this:

```
`$` <- function(a, b) { 
    res <- .Primitive("$")(a, b); 
    print(res); 
    if(is.null(res)) { print("null!") }; 
    return(res) 
}
```

It kind of seem to work, but:

```
> x$foobar
NULL
[1] "null!"
NULL
> x$foobar <- 3
> x$foobar
NULL
[1] "null!"
NULL
>
```

So it seems to stay null despite the override.

Comment: Do you want `foo` to be a function?

Comment: @RuiBarradas no. It needs to be a number. I am editing the question, one sec

Comment: (1) Are you not able to assign `x$foobar <- function(...) "null!"`? If not that, then (2) look at [`?makeActiveBinding`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/bindenv.html).

Comment: @r2evans no, what I want is that R raises an error if I refer to an entry in an environment that has never been defined. I settle on doing so when it's NULL

Comment: "I want to override the behavior of the dollar operator" No. No, you do not want to do this

Comment: @HongOoi it is broken. It should not return NULL if I don't have a key

Comment: That's a feature, not a bug. No, you still do not want to do this

Comment: @HongOoi it's not a feature at all. If I make a typo, now my program will get a NULL and end up with an error somewhere else god knows where. Good luck finding the typo.

Comment: Of course it's a feature. It means you can write your code to handle arbitrarily named lists (which can be the result of complex APIs) without needing to know every name beforehand. Good luck typing all that out

Comment: @HongOoi That does not make any sense. You can absolutely handle arbitrarily named lists (their equivalent) in python as well, but if you use a name that returns garbage, it tells you wrote garbage.

Comment: Of course it makes sense. You just have to recalibrate your expectations so that "use a name that doesn't exist" -> "returns a value that doesnt exist".

Comment: @HongOoi stop arguing the impossible. It is a massive language design failure if a typo can go unnoticed and the computation keeps going. We've been battling this garbage on IMPLICIT NONE with Fortran 77.

Comment: Nonsense. The difference is that with R, you generally have a REPL that allows minute inspection of coding innards, unlike a program compiled from punch cards. This means debugging such typos takes seconds or minutes, rather than hours or days. And the ease of programming in R isn't even in the same universe as Fortran

Comment: @Hongooi It might blow your mind that there are some people who don't give a damn about the repl (which python has as well) and have to code complex, thousands of line applications in R where this stuff is vital.

Comment: @Hongooi And they also have to certify the safety and correctness of what they develop to regulatory bodies, because people's life depend on it.

Comment: "And they also have to certify the safety and correctness of what they develop to regulatory bodies" if regulatory bodies can handle SAS (talk to me about SAS), R will be a doddle

Comment: Ooh, another one: if regulatory bodies can handle C, they can handle anything

Comment: @HongOoi C is fully regulated by MISRA. Write better code? what kind of statement is that? A language should protect you from trivial mistakes and help you track them down, not let them go silently. It absolutely makes no sense that an undefined variable is reported as an error, but an undefined key in a list or, even worse, an environment, returns NULL. It is _WRONG_.

Comment: "C is fully regulated by MISRA" lol no

Comment: "A language should protect you from trivial mistakes and help you track them down, not let them go silently" A language should provide the expressive power to let you say what you want to do, without getting in the way. Isn't this fun?

Comment: My expectations have already been recalibrated: R is a garbage language that is still drowning in Fortran mistakes. There is no reasonable scenario in which that behavior makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Normal behavior of R's `environment`s:

```r
myenv <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
myenv$foo <- 3
class(myenv)
# [1] "environment"

myenv$foo
# [1] 3
myenv$foobar
# NULL
```

Let's define a super-class (I'll name it `environment2`, feel free to be creative here) and override `$` for that class:

```r
class(myenv) <- c("environment2", "environment")
`$.environment2` <- function(x, name) {
  stopifnot(name %in% names(x))
  NextMethod()
}
myenv$foo
# [1] 3
myenv$foobar
# Error in `$.environment2`(myenv, foobar) : name %in% names(x) is not TRUE
```

You can easily clean up that error if you'd like, either using an `if` statement with `stop`, or (in R-4 or newer) naming the conditions in `stopifnot`.

```r
`$.environment2` <- function(x, name) {
  if (!name %in% names(x)) stop("something meaningful", call. = FALSE)
  NextMethod()
}
`$.environment2` <- function(x, name) {
  stopifnot(
    "something meaningful" = name %in% names(x)
  )
  NextMethod()
}

### both render
myenv$foobar
# Error in `$.environment2`(myenv, foobar) : something meaningful
```

They are relatively equivalent, but with `if`/`stop`, you can reduce the error context:

```r
`$.environment2` <- function(x, name) {
  if (!name %in% names(x)) stop("something meaningful", call. = FALSE)
  NextMethod()
}
myenv$foobar
# Error: something meaningful
```

Comment: this requires I create a new class. I want to override it for any class, even the environment one.

Comment: Okay. The only way I know of to influence how `$` operates (since it is a primitive) is via `options("warnPartialMatchDollar")`. (Or via classes.)